# How do I upgrade an individual Nintex 2007 workflow to a separate SharePoint 2010 farm?

Tags: workflow, upgrade

We have a legacy SharePoint 2007 farm with Nintex Workflow 2007 installed. We are in the process of migrating our sites and applications to a new SharePoint 2010 farm with Nintex Workflow 2010.

How do I upgrade individual Nintex 2007 workflows to the 2010 environment? Is it as simple as exporting the workflow from the 2007 environment and importing it into the 2010 environment? Are the any other methods or gotchas to consider?

Note that the 2010 envionment is already installed configured, so copying entire the Nintex database(s) to the new environment is not an option. We don't necessarily want to bring over all of the workflows and Nintex content to the new environment.

Comment: Sorry, per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial, third-party products.  Instead, please ask your question using [Nintex's support site](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Support/Pages/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

At least there's an advice from Nintex itself in this [thread](http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/12251.aspx) for example:

> Please first upgrade to the latest version in 2007. Then export the
>   workflow...

So it may be a good strategy.